# TestMethod generates error CS0201

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

This may me a philosophical rant that I need to get out of my system, on the other hand I could be doing something wrong, if so please tell me!

I have a unit test the looks something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(NotImplementedException))]
public void Test_XXXAccess()
{
    ControlPoint.MyObject.XXXAccess;
}
```

Which checks that the property XXXAccess is not implemented when the test is run in a particular context. This test generates a compile error CS0201: **"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"** Which while I agree is an error in production code, I think is wrong applied to a unit test. Of course I can re-write the code to:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(NotImplementedException))]
public void Test_XXXAccess()
{
    MyType x = ControlPoint.MyObject.XXXAccess;
}
```

But this (for me) seems more incorrect as you now have assigned it into a variable to do nothing more than mute the error.

Is there a better way to write the test?

Comment: Unless you rely on side effects in the `get` method for your `XXXAccess` property, which in itself might be bad practice unless you're careful, I'd say that the second version is the only correct version. Asking the compiler to keep in mind that you intended something is kind of hard. :)

Comment: Hmmm... Well I am using a lot of 'Mock' objects that implement my public interfaces - these are the ones that throw the exceptions. My tests check that the calls get that far, as I have proxies that will throw a different exception if there is no permission to access the methods.... so I guess it could be bad practise - but it seemed the best way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check that that type *does not have a property* of that name, the test should use reflection on `typeof(whatever)`; if you want to check that the getter / setter **method** throws `NotImplementedException`, you need to actually **call** that method.

After all, you might have the getter implemented but not the setter; what would you want just 'mentioning' the property to do in this case? Better to actually call *the code you're interested in* and assert about what happens.

I suppose if it is the getter you are interested in, you *could* reflect to obtain the getter method, then just `Invoke` it (which wouldn't require declaring a local that you then don't use), but this would be far more verbose than what you've already identified as a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't use reflection because the property will always be there. This is a read-only property i.e. no setter, and I want to test that calling the getter throws the NotImplementedException ... The test that generates the error does just that, it should call the code I am interested in, but alas generates the error :(